# R multiple regression predict output has more values than contained in the test set

Tags: r, output, regression, rows

I am trying to train and test a linear regression model in a certain dataset

The following is the header of the training dataset

```
> head(TaxiTrain)
         id vendor_id     pickup_datetime    dropoff_datetime passenger_count
1 id2875421         2 2016-03-14 17:24:55 2016-03-14 17:32:30               1
2 id2377394         1 2016-06-12 00:43:35 2016-06-12 00:54:38               1
3 id3858529         2 2016-01-19 11:35:24 2016-01-19 12:10:48               1
4 id3504673         2 2016-04-06 19:32:31 2016-04-06 19:39:40               1
5 id2181028         2 2016-03-26 13:30:55 2016-03-26 13:38:10               1
6 id0801584         2 2016-01-30 22:01:40 2016-01-30 22:09:03               6
  pickup_longitude pickup_latitude dropoff_longitude dropoff_latitude
1        -73.98215        40.76794         -73.96463         40.76560
2        -73.98042        40.73856         -73.99948         40.73115
3        -73.97903        40.76394         -74.00533         40.71009
4        -74.01004        40.71997         -74.01227         40.70672
5        -73.97305        40.79321         -73.97292         40.78252
6        -73.98286        40.74220         -73.99208         40.74918
  store_and_fwd_flag trip_duration
1                  N           455
2                  N           663
3                  N          2124
4                  N           429
5                  N           435
6                  N           443
```

The traning set and contains 1458644 rows

The test set is similar to the training set except for 2 Columns

```
head(Taxitest)
         id vendor_id     pickup_datetime passenger_count pickup_longitude
1 id3004672         1 2016-06-30 23:59:58               1        -73.98813
2 id3505355         1 2016-06-30 23:59:53               1        -73.96420
3 id1217141         1 2016-06-30 23:59:47               1        -73.99744
4 id2150126         2 2016-06-30 23:59:41               1        -73.95607
5 id1598245         1 2016-06-30 23:59:33               1        -73.97021
6 id0668992         1 2016-06-30 23:59:30               1        -73.99130
  pickup_latitude dropoff_longitude dropoff_latitude store_and_fwd_flag
1        40.73203         -73.99017         40.75668                  N
2        40.67999         -73.95981         40.65540                  N
3        40.73758         -73.98616         40.72952                  N
4        40.77190         -73.98643         40.73047                  N
5        40.76147         -73.96151         40.75589                  N
6        40.74980         -73.98051         40.78655                  N
```

The test set contains 625134 observations

Now I am facing two problems.I have trained a linear regression model :

```
lm1 <- lm(trip_duration ~ passenger_count, data = TaxiTrain)
```

This trains a linear regression model on the training set. When I fit this on the test set I use the following code.

```
lm2 <- predict(lm1, data = Taxitest)
```

I get 1458644 observations(Same as the training set). I am supposed to get 625134 predictions

I am not sure where the error is. I Request someone to clarify

Comment: Seems suspicious to me that you get back 1458644 observations when neither of your datasets have that many. This suggests that your train dataset has 1458644 observations instead of 1457644 that you mentioned.

Comment: I understand. Its a datset available on Kaggle. I have run the predict function in the past and have faced no problems. last week This has emerged. I have tried to reinstall R as well. No effect

Comment: MY mistake. The number of rows in the training set is also 1458644. the output of the predict function gives the same-1458644.

Comment: Great. Check my answer below. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank You Sir. Will check the same

Comment: Wow. That was neat and I think It has solved the issue. Thank You immensely sir. Ive been hammering away for weeks on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `lm2<-predict(lm1, newdata=Taxitest)` instead.

Check how this command works using `?predict.lm`. If you don't use `newdata=` it will predict on the dataset you used to train your model.

As an example see below:

```
# train and test sets
dt1 = mtcars[1:15,]
dt2 = mtcars[20:23,]

# build the model
lm = lm(disp ~ drat, data = dt1)

# check the differences / similarities
predict(lm, data=dt2)
predict(lm, newdata=dt2)
predict(lm, dt2)
```

Comment: `data =` won't work inside the `predict` command. It works only with `newdata=`. I'll correct the thing you mentioned. Sounds reasonable... :)

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. So It will not complain with `data =` and run it incorrectly while the correct argument is `newdata =` ?

Comment: Indeed it won't complain. It just ignores it. Like using `predict(lm)`.

Comment: Ok. Endiaferwn. Good catch :)

Comment: Indeed file! :D Typically I try to add the predictions as a new column to my test dataset and that's why I manage to catch this bug all the time (i.e. different length). Otherwise it's very likely you'll miss it.

Comment: I had a similar case recently with eval/parse. The thing though, if you do `eval(parse('5+5'))` it will throw an error since it needs to be `eval(parse(text = '5+5'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151186/discussion-between-sotos-and-antoniosk).